# Java Streams with Optional how transforming works

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, option-type

I can't understand the concept of optional and streams when used with map() vs flatMap().

**I understand this code :**

```
public String getCarInsurance(Optional<Person> optPerson) {
    return optPerson.flatMap(Person::getCar) //Returns Optional<Car>
            .flatMap(Car::getInsurance) //Returns Optional<Insurance>, .map would give Optional<Optional<Insurance>>
            .map(Insurance::getName) //no need for flatmap because getName returns String, not Optional<String>
            .orElse("UNKNOWN"); //returns value or Unknown
}
```

**But, I can't understand this code :**

```
 public Set<String> getCarInsuranceNames(List<Person> persons) {
        return persons.stream()
                .map(Person::getCar) //Convert the list of persons into Stream Optional<Car> 
                .map(optCar -> optCar.flatMap(Car::getInsurance)) //I don't understand this line
                .map(optIns -> optIns.map(Insurance::getName))
                .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                .collect(toSet());
    }
```

**edit:**

Why in this case we need `.map(optCar -> optCar.flatMap(Car::getInsurance))`, to get `Stream Optional<Insurance>` ? But in first code `.map(Car::getInsurance)` was enough to get `Optional<Insurance>`.

I understand why we need `.flatmap` instead of `.map` in first code, but I can't understand the pipeline of Stream in second code.

In second code `.map(Person::getCar)` returns `Stream Optional<Car>` and then we use `.map(optCar -> optCar.flatMap(Car::getInsurance))>` to get `Stream Optional<Insurance>` . Why wouldn't `.flatmap(Car::getInsurance)` get us `Stream Optional<Insurance>` ? This what I fail to understand.

**edit:** Domain classes below if needed.

```
public class Insurance {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }   
}

public class Car {
    Optional<String> name;
        public Optional<String> getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public class Person {
            Optional<Car> car;
            public Optional<Car> getCar(){
                return car;
            }
        }
```

Comment: btw, where did you get this code ?

Comment: Hello, it is from Modern Java in Action book.

Answer (score 3):

If you could keep both the code segments alike, it would help you understand

```
public String getCarInsurance(Optional<Person> optPerson) {
    return optPerson.flatMap(Person::getCar) //Returns Optional<Car>
            .flatMap(Car::getInsurance) //Returns Optional<Insurance>, .map would give Optional<Optional<Insurance>>
            .map(Insurance::getName) //no need for flatmap because getName returns String, not Optional<String>
            .orElse("UNKNOWN"); //returns value or Unknown
}

public Set<String> getCarInsuranceNames(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream()
            .map(person -> person.getCar() // chained in a similar manner as above
                    .flatMap(Car::getInsurance)
                    .map(Insurance::getName))
            .flatMap(Optional::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

or much cleaner if you could improve the existing contracts of your APIs to

```
public Optional<String> getCarInsurance(Person person) {
    return person.getCar() //Returns Optional<Car>
            .flatMap(Car::getInsurance) //Returns Optional<Insurance>, .map would give Optional<Optional<Insurance>>
            .map(Insurance::getName); //no need for flatmap because getName returns String, not Optional<String>
}

public Set<String> getCarInsuranceNames(List<Person> persons) {
    return persons.stream()
            .flatMap(person -> getCarInsurance(person).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why writing all chained statement in the same parentheses works, what effect it gives? In both cases `.map(person -> person.getCar() ` returns `Optional<Car>`. In this case we can call `.flatMap`
`persons.stream()  .map(person -> person.getCar()  .flatMap(Car::getInsurance)
  .map(Insurance::getName))`  .  `.map(person -> person.getCar() ` gives us `<Optional<Car>> Stream<Optional<Car>>` , and then we can call `flatMap(Car::getInsurance)`   .  But this doesn't work:  `.map(person -> person.getCar() ).flatMap(Car::getInsurance).map(Insurance::getName)`

Comment: @JamesLar Writing the chained statement in the same parenthesis was more around relating it to your existing code. Functionally it doesn't change anything. The confusion might be arising from the fact that both `Optional` and `Stream` has an API `flatMap`, which flattens the corresponding type and not the other. So you cannot call `flatMap` a `Stream` to change  and flatten an `Optional` return type.

Comment: Thank you. I understood that you refactored the code to make it relating to existing code, and its output is the same.  I can't  understand why the code you wrote, in parenthesis is good and compiles, but if we remove parentheses, the code no longer compiles. For example why `.map(person -> person.getCar() . flatMap(args) )` is valid, but 
`.map(person -> person.getCar() ) . flatMap(args) ` is not valid.  how the parenthesis change flow of the code.

Comment: @JamesLar As I said, it's because of the return type involved, in the former `.map(person -> person.getCar(). flatMap(args))`, the `Optional#flatMap` is invoked on `Opttional<Car>` and flattens it to `Optional<Insurance>` and that woks. On the other hand with `.map(person -> person.getCar()).flatMap(args)` the `Stream#flatMap` is called on `Steam<Optional<Car>>` and since you are dealing with `Optional` in args and not a `Stream`, hence that fails.

Answer (score 1):

It's done to avoid nesting of `Optional`. `optCar` is of type `Optional<Car>`. If we invoked `map(optCar -> optCar.map(Car::getInsurance))` instead of `map(optCar -> optCar.flatMap(Car::getInsurance))`, then we would end up having `Stream<Optional<Optional<Insurance>>>`.

But nesting optional does not make much sense, if we have `optA` of type `Optional<A>` and there is a method `A#getB`, that returns `Optional<B>`, then we can simplify the code by invoking `optA.flatMap(A::getB)`, which will result in `Optional<B>`:

```
Optional<B> optB = optA.flatMap(A::getB);
Optional<Optional<B>> optOptB = optA.map(A::getB); // don't do that
```

`optA.flatMap(A::getB)` works intuitively - if `optA` is empty or if `optA` has value, but `optA.getB()` is empty, then the result of the `flatMap` will be an empty `Optional<B>`. Only if `optA` has a value and `optA.getB()` is not null, the result will not be empty.

In the first snippet `flatMap` was enough, because it's an operation on `Optional`, whereas in the second snippet we're operation on a `Stream`.

Comment: Thanks. (concisely) What i really fail to understand:  is in first, Person::getCar returns <Car>, then (Car::getInsurance) returns <Insurance>. But in second we need to write .map(optCar -> optCar.flatMap(Car::getInsurance)) to get Insurance,  .map(Car::getInsurance) doesnt work. I really dont understand concept of this and action behind the scenes.

Comment: @JamesLar that is not true, in the first snippet you wrote `.flatMap(Car::getInsurance) //Returns Optional<Insurance>, .map would give Optional<Optional<Insurance>>`, which means `Car#getInsurance` returns `Optional<Insurance>` and not `Insurance` as you claim

Comment: Yes, sorry I tried to write concisely. `flatMap(Person::getCar) //Returns Optional<Car>   , .flatMap(Car::getInsurance) //Returns Optional<Insurance>`
Then in second code <code>.map(Person::getCar)  //Returns Stream Optional<Car></code> And then we use  <code>.map(optCar -> optCar.flatMap(Car::getInsurance))</code> to get Stream Optional<Insurance> .  Why wouldn't .flatmap(Car::getInsurance) get us  Stream Optional<Insurance> .  This what I fail to `understand`.

Comment: @JamesLar be careful on what you're calling `flatMap`. On `Stream` it flattens inner `Stream`, on `Optional`, it flattens inner `Optional`.

Comment: @Andronicus - Is there any nice tutorial on how map and flatMap work with optionals. It looks like the behavior with optionals is special.

Comment: Why should it be special? `map` produces `Optional<Optional<T>>`, whereas `flatMap` - `Optional<T>`. Here is a nice one with whole paragraphs on `map` and `flatMap`: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html